# Unity does't create apk by script before folder is opened by editor

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, continuous-integration

I'm trying to create CI pipeline with gitlab and Unity. I want crete apk from script(command line)

```
START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchmode -quit -executeMethod BuildScript.BuildAndroid -logfile build.log
```

It works fine if I execute it from folder that I alredy opened with unity Editor. But if I try to do this from new folder (generated from gitlab runner), it doesn't create apk.